# Controlling emission strength with bone driver?

Tags: drivers

I have a rigged model where some bones which are constrained to a certain y location length. I would like to control an emission strength with these bones if possible.

I've added drivers to emission strength and set drivers to sum value and selected the bones. It kind of works, problem is it only works if I take off the limit location constraint on the bones. How do I get this to work within the limited area? value 0 to 5 strength for example?

Comment: You could use the graph of the driver to extrapolate horizontally after (5, 5). I couldn't reproduce your problem, the driver works fine with and without the Limit Location constraint. Show your settings of the constraint/driver/whatever isn't working or upload your file.

Comment: Hey, here's a blend file i've made as simple as posible.

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4873" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4873/)

Turn the upper left panel to rendered to see the blue flame. On the same object is a sphere with a different shader, emission. Its that I want to change with either the empty or bone

Thanks

Comment: You have a single key in the graph of the driver, which is extrapolated near horizontal. It is common to map the variable linearly with two keys: (0, 0) and (1, 1). Also, place the variable's name **var** in the expression field to use it. Refer to [this setup](https://imgur.com/a/zvI67Ht).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Been playing with the drivers for a few hours. Got it working! Although I still don't have the green line like your picture, just the ref one, for some reason I got it working perfectly....not sure how.

I need to study drivers a lot more...